# Javascript not allowing actually image to be linked out

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get my website to link the slider image. Nothing in my wordpress has the options, so I opened up the slider php from the file manager, and I am trying to figure out exactly what I need to do to enable the image to link out without having to put on the "caption". [Here is the website](http://dietsystemcouponcodes.com/)

```
<div id="home-slide-wrapper">
                <div id="home-slide" class="<?php echo $img_slide_effect_direction; ?>">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <?php 
                            foreach( $slides as $slide ) : 
                            $image_id = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'info_image', true);

                            // $resized_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full');
                            // $resized_image_src = $resized_image_src[0];

                            $resized_image_src = theme_get_image( $image_id, 5000, $img_slide_height, true );

                            // Caption
                            $caption_pos = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'info_caption_pos', true);
                            $caption_title = __(get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'info_caption_title', true));
                            $caption_text = __(get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'info_caption', true));
                            $link = __(get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'info_link', true));

                            // Pre-Process
                            $caption_title = ( $link != '' && $caption_title != '' ) ? '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $caption_title  . '</a>' : $caption_title;

                            $caption_title_bg_tone = 'slide-caption-bg-' . getDarkLightYIQ( $sitewide_caption_title_bg_color );
                            $caption_style[] = ( $sitewide_caption_title_text_color != '' ) ? 'color:' . $sitewide_caption_title_text_color . ';' : '';
                            $caption_style[] = 'background-color:' . $sitewide_caption_title_bg_color . ';';
                            $caption_title_style = 'style="' . implode( ' ', $caption_style ) . '"';
                        ?>
                            <li>

                                <img src="<?php echo $resized_image_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide->post_title; ?>" />

                                <?php if( $caption_title || $caption_text ): ?>
                                <div class="slide-caption <?php echo $caption_pos; ?>">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <?php if( $caption_title != '' ) : ?>
                                        <div class="slide-caption-headline <?php echo $caption_title_bg_tone; ?>"><?php echo $caption_title; ?></div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if( $caption_text ) : ?>
                                        <div class="slide-caption-text"><?php echo $caption_text; ?></div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

        </div><!-- #home-slide-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Just wrap the `<img>` in an `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you be more specific? Is there a place in the code I should add that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<img src="<?php echo $resized_image_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide->post_title; ?>" />
```

with

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
  <img src="<?php echo $resized_image_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide->post_title; ?>" />
</a>
```

Comment: Wow, incredible work Chris. You are THE MAN. Thank you